# Parent view not keep its orientation, after dismiss model view controller in ios

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I m developing iphone app. In that all viewcon`enter code here`troller support all orientation. But one of my `navigationController` stack content want to present one 
`viewcontroller` in `Landscape` `orientation` only. I done this by creating one custon UINavigationController with rootviewcontroller as my `modelviewcontroller` ,it support only landscape mode and it works fine when the parentviewcontroller in portrait modd, but the parentviewcontroller in landscape it present modelview controller as landscape fine but after dismiss the `modelViewcontroller` the `parentviewcontroller` as portrait, but the `self.view` and `subview` are in landscape.
 Please help me.. I put my code and screenshot as below..

**.m file in custom navigationcontroller I done this..**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL) automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers {
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

**.m file parentView**

//This is my  presentViewcintroller code

```
VideoPreviewViewController *videoPreviewVC = [[VideoPreviewViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"VideoPreviewViewController" bundle:nil];
customNavigationController = [[CLNotRotatingNavController alloc]initWithRootViewController:videoPreviewVC];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:customNavigationController animated:YES completion:nil];

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;
}
```

.m file in modelviewcontroller

```
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: if you got fixed! then post here what you did!